# How to repeat characters in Python without string concatenation?

Tags: python, string, concatenation, format-string

I'm currently writing a short program that does frequency analysis. However, there's one line that is bothering me:

```
"{0[0]}  | " + "[]" * num_occurrences + " Total: {0[1]!s}"
```

Is there a way in Python to repeat certain characters an arbitrary number of times without resorting to concatenation (preferably inside a format string)? I don't feel like I'm doing this in the most Pythonic way.

Comment: Could clarify a bit more i.e add some trivial sample i/p and o/p

Comment: `"{0}  | {1} Total: {2!s}".format("Some val", "[]"*10, "not string")` May be this what you are looking for.

Comment: Can't believe that I didn't think of that. Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The best way to repeat a character or string is to multiply it:

```
>>> "a" * 3
'aaa'
>>> '123' * 3
'123123123'
```

And for your example, I'd probably use:

```
>>> "{0[0]}  | {1} Total: {0[1]!s}".format(foo, "[]" * num_occurrences)
```

Comment: I think the OP is already doing this, with `"[]" * num_occurrences`

Comment: @jedwards the latter part of the question dealt with concatenation, as does the latter part of my answer :)

Comment: Hmmm.. I feel like that wasn't there originally.. :-P  Okay fair enough.